# Output for finding the time in 24 hour input given in 12hour format(without using any inbuild class)

Tags: java, string

> I am trying to convert the time given in 12hr format to 24 hour format.

But I am not getting expected output when the time is in AM.

> Can Anyone guide me why?

Input form

HH:MM:SS

**MyApproach**

To convert the time in 24 hr format I checked if the time is given in AM,
I printed the output as it is.
If the time is given in PM,I added 12 Hours to the time

Below is my function:

```
public static String timeConversion(String time)
 {   
    String strnew1="";
    String strnew2="";
    String strnew="";
    String strnew3="";

    boolean b1=true;
    for(int i=time.length()-2;i<time.length();i++)
        {
             strnew=strnew+time.charAt(i);
        }


    if(strnew=="AM")

    {

     b1=false;
     for(int m=0;m<time.length()-2;m++)
     {
           strnew3=strnew3+time.charAt(m); 
     }
     System.out.println("jhh");

     System.out.println(strnew3);

    }



    else
    {
       for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
       {
                                                                                     strnew1=strnew1+time.charAt(j);

       }



     int a=Integer.parseInt(strnew1);
     int b=a+12;
     strnew2=b+strnew2;
     for(int k=2;k<time.length()-2;k++)
     {
         strnew2=strnew2+time.charAt(k);
     }

   }
if(b1==false)
return strnew3;
else
return strnew2;

 }

}

**OutputShown**

Input              OutputShown           Expected Output
05:32:32AM         17:32:32              05:32:32
```

Comment: Why don't you use predefined class `SimpleDateFormat`instead of writing your own?

Comment: I can't use that.A kind of test

Comment: Please format your code properly and remove all irrelevant parts, such as empty loops and nonsensical print statements.

Comment: Pro tip: Find better variable names and your code will do it in no time. The names you use is representative of how much you understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here

```
if(strnew=="AM")
```

Strings in Java are compared like this:

```
if(strnew.equals("AM"))
```

But there is also another problem 12PM should become 12 and 12AM should become 00. You need to check for these special cases.

Comment: Yes,I am converting it.If any error come I will Comment here.